# Representation of diedral group $D_8$, why $\rho(a)^2=1$ if $a$ is the rotation?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I recall that $D_8=<a,b\mid a^4=b^2=1, bab=a^3>$. I have to determine all representation $\rho:D_8\longrightarrow \mathbb C^*$ of degree 1 of $D_8$. In my course it's written that since $\rho(a)^2=\rho(b)^2=1$, then $\rho(a)=\pm 1$ and $\rho(b)=\pm 1$ (and thus such representation follow). The problem is that for me $\rho(a)^4=1$, and thus $\rho(a)\in\{1,i,-1,-i\}$. So, I don't understand why we don't consider $i$ and $-i$. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You first have that $[\mathcal D_8:\mathcal D_8]=\left<a^2\right>.$ Moreover, since $$\rho: \mathcal D_8\longrightarrow \mathbb C^*,$$
the group $$\mathcal D_8/\ker(\rho)\cong \text{Im}(\rho)\leq \mathbb C^*.$$
Since $\mathbb C^*$ is abelian, you get that $\mathcal D_8/\ker(\rho)$ is abelian, and thus that $[\mathcal D_8,\mathcal D_8]\leq \ker(\rho)$. If you are not conviced about this result, show that $G/H$ is abelian $\iff [G,G]\leq H$ where $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Therefore, $$\rho(a^2)=\rho(a)^2=1,$$
what prove the claim.